# Hierarchical Bayes estimation in Conjoint Analysis

Tags: r, hierarchical-bayesian, regression-coefficients, conjoint-analysis

I require some assistance with HLM Conjoint Analysis.

Say a preference-survey asks multiple respondents which of three products they prefer, using different combinations of product features (each respondent answers multiple times with different product combinations each time). For example, a single choice may be do you prefer:

- medium blue car priced at $20,000
- small red car priced at $16,000
- large yellow car priced at $19,000

How would I create utility / feature coefficients from such data? I am looking to create coefficients for each product feature (e.g. Car colour: blue, red, yellow) for every individual respondent using HLM. Is there a R package that is capable of this?

Answer (score 4):

I think you're looking for the [ChoiceModelR](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ChoiceModelR) package.  You specify a utility function, and the package will estimate coefficients, or part-worth utilities, using a hierarchical multinomial logit model.

Answer (score 0):

For Bayesian choice modelling, I would strongly advise you to take a look at:
**RSGHB** package - Very flexible as you basically need to write your own utility functions
**bayesm** package (The book that goes with this package is a great introduction to HB: http://eu.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-0470863676.html)